# Multigroup CFA with different model specification

Tags: r, purrr, r-lavaan, factor-analysis

I want to run a Multigroup CFA. Below, I used a well-known data set available in lavaan to create a reproducible example . The data set contains performance data on intelligence tasks of students enrolled in two schools. The purpose of the study is to confirm the structure of the latent variables across the groups.

Although the measurement model is the same for the groups, I want to test different structural models between group 1 (school = "Pasteur") and group 2 (school = "Grant-White"). How can I do that? One way to deal with this scenario is to use `purrr::map_if` and pre-specify the two structures. Unfortunately, this approach does not perform well when you have more than two groups or you need to do additional analyses with the loading values.

I am wondering if there is a way to specify this information (e.g., textual ~ speed = NA or something) within the `lavaan::cfa` function.

Thanks to anyone who will help!

```
library(lavaan)
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

HS.model <- ' visual =~ x1 + x2 + x3
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 
              visual ~ speed
              textual ~ speed'

fit <- cfa(HS.model, 
           data = HolzingerSwineford1939, 
           group = "school")

summary(fit)

HS.model1 <- 'visual =~ x1 + x2 + x3
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 
              visual ~ speed
              textual ~ speed'

HS.model2 <- ' visual =~ x1 + x2 + x3
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 
              visual ~ speed'

HolzingerSwineford1939 %>% 
  group_by(school) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(m = data %>% map_if((school == "Pasteur"), function(d) cfa(HS.model1, data = d)),
                m = m %>% map_if((school == "Grant-White"), function(d) cfa(HS.model2, data = d)),
                stdsol = m %>% 
                  map(function(fit) standardizedsolution(fit))) %>% 
  unnest(stdsol) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  dplyr::filter(op != "~~") %>% 
  unite(Effect, lhs, op, rhs, sep = "") %>% 
  dplyr::select(school, Effect, est.std) %>% 
  tidyr::spread(school, est.std)
```

Comment: have you checked the [lavaan tutorial on multiple groups](http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/groups.html)?

Comment: I have. In the section "Fixing parameters in some groups, but not all", the author explained how to estimate different parameters across groups for the measurement model. When I try to apply the same logic to the structural model (i.e., `textual * c(NA, 0) ~ speed)`, it does not work.